# Sharepoint Wiki: Can you embed anything other than images and hyperilnks? Specifically, .swf?

Tags: sharepoint, video, wiki, flash, swf

Is it possible to embed anything other than hyperlinks and pictures in a Sharepoint Wiki?  I was trying to insert a client-side .swf flash video, but I am having some trouble, since it seems that `<object>` tags are being removed.  If I can't embed .swf files, are there video file types I can embed (such as Windows media types) in a wiki?

I believe we are using an older Sharepoint interface (Windows SharePoint Services 3.0), so I'm not sure how much of this applies in Sharepoint 2007 or other Sharepoint versions.

Comment: WSS 3.0 and SharePoint 2007 is the same project. SharePoint 2007 contains the enterprise features. WSS 3.0 is the core for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint strips those tags by default. You might want to check out this project:
http://www.codeplex.com/erte to see if it works.

Comment: This works EXCELLENTLY.  Exactly what I needed.  Took me a while to get access to modify the _catalogs/masterpage for the site, but boy, is it a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Telerik RadControls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/sharepoint.aspx), however the particular functionality for embedding Flash is not freely available.

Answer (score 0):

This annoyed us too.  Guess what - it's in Sharepoint 2010.  Good old Microsoft.  Always holding back features so the next upgrade is compelling.

Comment: Are there any places you know that have links to doing this?  I'm trying out Sharepoint 2010, and I don't see much of a change in the way wikis are structured to know if this is true.

Comment: To be honest, I only head that this was going to be in Sharepoint 2010 at a Microsoft event - I haven't seen it for myself.